# Python Except Errors (multiple errors)

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, geolocation

I am using python 3. I use database to lookup the country of IP, if the IP is not in the database, return None or AAA. After all process, show the return result (either a country name or None or AAA ) in a new column on the data frame, Specifically, I have three columns that are date time and IP in the data frame, I would like to add a new column "code1" that shows the country name or None of this IP.

I add error exception in the code, however, it doesn't work. The code and error message are as below. Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

The following is the report when I add "from geoip2.errors import AddressNotFoundError" to my code. I guess it means when there is address not found in the database, it return nothing rather a "none" (see, there is a empty square brackets), therefore, when I use df['code1']=code1, it reports the number of value is not equal to the number of index. (I am not sure).

In fact,my aim is to add a column to my original data frame that report the country of each ip or none if it is not in the database. Is there any other way to do so instead of " df['code1']=code1 "? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are just like any other object in Python. They have to be defined somewhere. In this case, `AddressNotFoundError` is not defined so the interpreter has no idea what it means.

It has to be imported:

```
from geoip2.errors import AddressNotFoundError
```

or

```
import geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError
```

See relevant part of geoip2 [documentation](https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError).

Comment: Thank you for help. it does not work as well, I add import geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError, it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError'; 'geoip2.errors' is not a package
"

Comment: I am so sorry I don't know how to past the screen shot properly above. It shows a link rather the picture.. If you click the picture links above, it shows what reports when I add from geoip2.errors import AddressNotFoundError. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave out the AddressNotFoundError and instead do

```
try:
    response1 = reader.country(row1)
    code1.append(response1.country.iso_code)
except:
    response1 = None
```

but if you really want to just except the AddressNotFoundError then at the top do

```
import geoip.errors.AddressNotFoundError
```

Comment: I'll try this out for myself, what version of python are you running?

Comment: when I leave out the AddressNotFoundError, it returns "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".  Further, when i add "import geoip.errors.AddressNotFoundError", it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoip'".

Comment: I just realized you should try this: from geoip2.errors import AddressNotFoundError

Comment: I use python 3.

Comment: I am so sorry I don't know how to past the screen shot properly above. It shows a link rather the picture.. If you click the picture links above, it shows what reports when I add from geoip2.errors import AddressNotFoundError. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: where can i get the csv file you have, i cannot get python to fall into the for loop without it.